# Can you overlay a graph over an image in dart?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRqq8.png)

Basically I have an image that's a prexisting graph and I want to be able to allow the user to place a single dot by giving the x and y.

Is that possible in dart/flutter?

I haven't really given it a proper try yet because I'm not really sure how to go about this. I've just been trying to find workarounds for now.

Comment: Try Stack widget - it allows you to put multiple widgets over each other. Your bottom widget will be your graph; and above it just place a simple widget that shows a dot wherever you want it.